# awk print only lines between two patterns removing first match

Tags: regex, bash, awk

This one prints between the two patterns

`printf "/n"| openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443 | awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/'`

Then this one removes the first matching set but then prints all the superfluous junk

`printf "/n"| openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443 | awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/{f=1;++c} !(f && c==2); /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{f=0}'`

I would like to get the second results with out the extra stuff outside the pattern matches I could by just using two awks.

`printf "/n"| openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443 | awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/' | awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/{f=1;++c} !(f && c==2); /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{f=0}'`

But I wanted to do it in one if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889352/sed-remove-first-pattern-match-only), and I'd adapt my sed answer as follows:

```
sed -n '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ { // { x; s/$/./; x; }; x; /.../ { x; p; x; }; x; }' filename
```

That is

```
/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {
  // {           
    x
    s/$/./      #  keep a counter of boundary lines in the hold buffer
    x
  }
  x             # inspect the counter
  /.../ {       # if counter >= 3
    x
    p           # print the line
    x
  }
  x
}               # with -n, falling off the end here will not lead to printing.
```

Alternatively, the sanest awk I can think of is

```
awk '/----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----/ { flag = 1; ++ctr } flag && ctr >= 2 { print } /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ { flag = 0 }' filename
```

more readably:

```
/----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----/ {  # beginning of a range:
  flag = 1                     # raise flag that we're in one
  ++ctr                        # count in which one
}
flag && ctr >= 2 { print }     # print only if in a range and not in the first
/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {  # when leaving
  flag = 0                     # lower flag
}
```